# Select field 1 Where Field 2 ='value1' And field 2 ='value2' when Field 1 is Same

Tags: sql, select, count, having-clause

I am currently having troubles with filtering my SQL records. I need something like what it results in the following concept: Table is


```
A   B
1   1
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
3   1
3   2
```

I want to select value of A , where B=1 and B=2 And B=3 when same A .... result is

```
A
2
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select a
from mytable
where b in (1, 2, 3)
group by a
having count(*) = 3
```

This assumes no duplicates in the table - else, you need to change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct b) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks , But when  table has groups of three records (A, B with same values) , result is incorrect. if exist thrice same record,  like A = 4 ,B=1, not success. help